# Оценка качества линейной регрессии sklearn LinearRegression

Tags: python, sklearn

У меня есть обученная на тренировочной выборке (0,8) модель.

```
x = df['mentee_cnt'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y = df['mentor_cnt'].to_numpy()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)

print('mse: %.3f, rmse: %.3f, mae: %.3f' % (mse, np.sqrt(mse), mae))
print("Coefficients: \n", model.coef_)
print('Independent: \n', model.intercept_)
print("r2_score: \n", r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Метрики оценки качества модели рассчитаны.
Но у меня возникает простой вопрос.

Когда я проверяю нормальность распределения остатков и однородность дисперсии остатков, остатки мне следует брать для валидационной выборки?

P. S. Ранее я решал похожую задачу для дипломной работы в Statistica и не задумывался (плохая методичка) по поводу разделения данных на тренировочную и валидационную выборки. А сам пакет Statistica по-умолчанию строил нужные графики на основе тренировочной выборки.

Comment: Всё обучение только на трейне, вся валидация только на тесте. Пересекаться они не должны, чтобы отловить возможное переобучение.

Comment: А что же вы код для того, о чём спрашиваете, не добавили? )  Ну а так по идее да, проверять всё надо на тесте/валидации, особенно для более сложных моделей, чем `LR`, сложные модели могут трейн почти идеально выучить и поэтому метрики на трейне вам ни о чём не скажут. Для простой модели вроде `LR` можно и на трейне тоже метрики посмотреть, но только ради интереса.

Comment: В некотором смысле код в вопросе лишний. =) Вопросов по написанию кода нет.

Comment: Ну так то да, без данных в общем смысла нет. Но если бы был код с генерацией данных и полным циклом того, о чём вопрос, можно было бы покрутить код, визуализировать всякое. А так лениво. )